# How to Iterate through only Qualified elements, not all

Tags: jquery

If I have Checkboxes in page with IDs like below

```
a_chk1, a_chk2, a_chk3, b_chk1, b_chk2, b_chk3, c_chk1, c_chk2
```

If I want to retrieve checkboxes with ID starting with "a_". The below code done my work

```
$(':checkbox').filter(function(){return $(this).prop('id').indexOf("a_") > -1;})
```

But it iterates through each checkbox and filters the required elements. But `is there any possibility of iterating through only qualified elements`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can let jQuery do all the work for you in the selector like this:

```
$(':checkbox[id^="a_"]')
```

Working demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5qENn/

Answer (score 1):

No, unless you give them classes as well (e.g. `class="a"` to the first three, etc). If you do, then you could use `$(".a:checkbox")` or similar.

Comment: [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) is cleaner

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, do this :

```
$(':checkbox[id^="a_"]').each(function() {

});
```

Uses the [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and iterates using [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)

Answer (score 1):

I guess this iterates too under the hood but it's cleaner.

```
$('input:checkbox[id^="a_"]')
```